# Converting stream to string in node.js

Tags: node.js, string, stream

I am reading a file which comes in as an attachment like follows

```
let content = fs.readFileSync(attachmentNames[index], {encoding: 'utf8'});
```

When I inspect content, it looks ok, I see file contents but when I try to assign it to some other variable

```
attachmentXML = builder.create('ATTACHMENT','','',{headless:true})
            .ele('FILECONTENT',content).up()
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Invalid character in string: PK
```

There are a couple of rectangular boxes (special characters) after PK in the above message which are not getting displayed.

builder here refers to an instance of the xmlbuilder https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder node module.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by enclosing the string inside a JS escape() method